# Phase freedom of the edge states in topological insulator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

Suppose that we consider the BHZ-like Hamiltonian of the form
$$
H_{bulk}=\left(M-B k^{2}\right) \tau_{z}-A k_{x} \tau_{y}+A k_{y} \sigma_{z} \otimes \tau_{x}
$$
where $\tau_i $ acts on the orbital degrees of freedom and $\sigma_i$ acts on the spin degree of freedoms.
Then we derive the edge state form in the x and y edges respectively.

In the $x=0$ boundary, $k_x$ need to be replaced by $-i \partial_{x}$, then the effective Hamiltonian becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\mathrm{eff}}\left(-i \partial_{x}, k_{y}\right)=&\left(M+B \partial_{x}^{2}\right) \tau_{z}+i A \partial_{x} \tau_{y} \\
&-B k_{y}^{2} \tau_{z}+A k_{y} \sigma_{z} \otimes \tau_{x}
\end{aligned}
$$
For $k_y = 0,$ the second line vanishes and the equation can be expressed as
$$
\left[\left(M+B \partial_{x}^{2}\right) \tau_{z}+i A \partial_{x} \tau_{y}\right] \psi_{0}(x)=E \psi_{0}(x)
$$
with the particle-hole symmetry of the equation, a zero energy solution exists such that
$$
\left[\left(M+B \lambda^{2}\right) \tau_{x} \phi=-A \lambda \phi\right.
$$
where we assume $\psi_{0}(x)=\phi e^{\lambda x}$.

So $\phi$ should be the eigenstate of $\sigma_x$ in order to be a solution. With the normalizable condition of $\psi_0$ ($\lambda$ should be negetive), $\phi$ should be the eigenstate of $\sigma_x$ with positive eigenvlues (assume $A$ and $B$ are both positive). We can write the two solutions as
$$
\Psi_{\uparrow}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi^{x}_{+} \\
\mathbf{0}
\end{array}\right), \quad \Psi_{\downarrow}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{0} \\
\phi^{x}_{+}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\tau_{x} \phi^{y}_{s}=s \phi^{y}_{s}(s=\pm)$

At boundary $y=0$, the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\mathrm{eff}}\left(k_x , - i \partial_{y}\right)=&\left(M+B \partial_{y}^{2}\right) \tau_{z} - i A \partial_{y} \sigma_z \otimes \tau_{x} \\
&-B k_{x}^{2} \tau_{z} - A k_{x}  \tau_{y}
\end{aligned}
$$
For $k_x = 0$,
the function becomes
$$
[\left(M+B \partial_{y}^{2}\right) \tau_{z} - i A \partial_{y} \sigma_z \otimes \tau_{x}] \psi_{0}(y) =E \psi_{0}(y)
$$
assuming $\psi_{0}(y)=\phi e^{\lambda y}$, equation can be simplified
$$
\left[\left(M+B \lambda^{2}\right) \tau_{y} \phi=-A \lambda \sigma_z \phi\right.
$$
which is similar to the case at edge x. So the edge mode can be written as
$$
\Psi_{\uparrow}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_{+}^{y} \\
0
\end{array}\right), \quad \Psi_{\downarrow}(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{0} \\
\phi_{-}^{y}
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\tau_{y} \phi^{y}_{s}=s \phi^{y}_{s}(s=\pm)$

Now consider the perturbation term which mixes up the up and down spin channel, such as $H_{\Delta} = \sigma_x \otimes \tau_o$ (this can be achieved by applying a Zeeman field), if we want to know the effective theory of this perturbation on the boundary, we should project this perturbation to the boundary state
$$
\left\langle\Psi_{\mu}\left|H_{\Delta}\right| \Psi_{\nu}\right\rangle \quad(\mu, \nu=\uparrow, \downarrow)
$$
this generally gives a mass term added to the original Hamiltonian like $m \sigma_x$.

But here comes to the problem, it seems that there is a degree of freedom of phase in the solution of the edge states in $x= 0$ and $y= 0$ boundaries, and different choice of relative phase between up and down spin states obviously leads to different mass terms in each boundary.
For example, in the $x=0$ boundary we choose $$
\Psi_{\uparrow}(x)= - \left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi^{x}_{+} \\
\mathbf{0}
\end{array}\right), \quad \Psi_{\downarrow}(x)= \left(\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{0} \\
\phi^{x}_{+}
\end{array}\right)
$$
then the mass term is $-m \sigma_x$(instead of $m \sigma_x$ if we choose the up and down spin edge states to be the same phase). We could as well alter the mass term in the $y=0$ boundary by adjusting the relative phase between two states.

But the relative difference between mass terms of the two boundaries have physical consequences (whether there is a corner states), so in this sense the relative mass term should not depend on the phase choice.

How to solve this contradiction?